# Is there a better way to implement multithreading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, cpu-usage

The source code portion below makes the CPU consumes high! Is there a better way to implement multithreading?

```
// This application will run 24 hours 7 days per week
//     in server

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int NUM = 10;

    Thread[] t = new Thread[NUM];

    for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
        t[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork));

    foreach (Thread u in t)
        u.Start();
}

static void DoWork()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Perform scanning work
        // If some conditions are satisfied,
        //     it will perform some actions
    }
}
```

Comment: CPU is high because you are using `while(true)` Have a look at TPL, especially at `Task` or `Parallel` classes

Comment: Isn't the idea of multi-threading to make the most effective use of the CPU as possible? You're running a tight loop on multiple threads, so I'd hope to see that CPU usage is high as a result.

Comment: On a side note, consider using [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.8) over explicitly creating new Threads.

Comment: Is it possible to have an *event* "some conditions are satisfied, some work should be performed"? If not, can you check not in `while` loop, but, say, every `5` seconds?

Comment: You need to show us what's going on in the `while` block. If what you're doing is cpu intensive then you'll be eating up a lot of cpu time.

Comment: Note that with 10 threads you are more likely than not using all cores on your CPU, and given that there's an infinite loop in `DoWork`, having this code consume as much CPU usage as possible is what should be expected. If you want to run tasks on a schedule, use a `Timer` or QuartzScheduler.NET

Comment: Is there a better way to implement that my application can perform scanning action and other actions 24/7 in server, in order to make CPU consumes low?

Comment: Side note: CPUs are *different* (from obsolete single core up to 64 cores Epics), that's why *do not hardcode* `const int NUM = 10;` since `10` can well appear a bad choice; use `NUM = Environment.ProcessorCount;` or alike instead

Answer (score 1):

The question is hard to answer if it isn't clear what's inside the `while(true)` spinning loop. If you start 10 threads where each one does spinning without any waits (using something like `AutoResetEvent.WaitOne()`, `Thread.Sleep()`, etc.), the CPU will be consumed - since you are asking the CPU for it.

To improve overall performance threads shouldn't spin if it isn't absolutely necessary to do - and in most cases it isn't. Threads should do their work and then if there aren't more work to do, they should go to sleep. They should be woken up only if they have more work items to process. If your thread is running all the time - checking some conditions that are met only from time to time *and if you have a mechanism to inform your thread that conditions are true* - then the spinning is wasting of your CPU cycles.

Conceptually a thread should work in this way.

```
while(true)
{
    // Wait until a thread has something meaningful to do. Waiting can be done for instance by calling AutoResetEvent.WaitOne().

    // Do a meaningful work here.
}
```

If you do your thread code in this way, when a thread is waiting, it doesn't spend the CPU, so system is not overworked and other threads/processes can do their work.

The principal question here is, if you have some kind of notification mechanism that allows your thread to wake up when a new work item arrives. For instance, most IO operations like TCP sockets, HTTP communication, reading from files, etc. support asynchronous communication that allows your thread to go to sleep and awake only if new data arrive.

On the other hand, if you don't have such mechanism - for instance you are using a 3rd party library that doesn't notify you when something meaningful happened, you have to do some kind of spinning. But even it this case, the question is, how often do you need to check if conditions were met - so there is some work to do.

If let say, you need to check only every second if conditions were met, add `Thread.Sleep(1000)` calls to your thread code. This will greatly increases overal performance. Even `Thread.Sleep(0)` is much better then wait-less spinning.

One important note here. In modern C#, threads should not be used as your primary asynchronous programming mechanism. Using task based asynchronous programming using `class Task` is much easier to implement, especially if you are using `await-async` C# keywords and in most cases leads to better performance.

Tasks use threads internally creating new ones if there are too many work items to process with current number of threads and releasing threads, if there isn't enough work to do. Optimal number of threads reduces overal memory consumption.

In these days virtually all standard .NET APIs support task based asynchronous programming so it should be your primary tool how to achieve paralel execution of your code.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model) is some example of task based asynchronous programming.